# Insert a string at a specific position in a file with batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm new to batch script, I have a file with a string containing the word "media"(quotes included) and I need to insert another string right before it.
I messed around with findstr but couldn't make heads or tails of it.
**Edit2**:
here's what i did, doesn't seem to work:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
for /f "delims=," %%a in (f1.txt) do (  
set foo=%%a  
if !foo!=="media" 
set var=!foo:"media"=aa"media"!
echo !foo! >> f2.txt)
```

Comment: You can only do string substitution with the `SET` command in a batch-file.

Comment: but how do i find the word "media", then i can substitute it with my string+"media"

Comment: Use a `FOR /F` command to read the file. Use the `SET` command to assign the `FOR` variable to an environmental variable. Then use another `SET` command to do the string substitution.

Comment: Edit your question and update it with your code. Then delete your comment

Comment: Are you saying that the string **"media"** is on a line by itself?

Comment: no, the file contains only one line consisting of a long string that have the substring"media" in it

Comment: That last comment would have been useful in your original question.  Just reading the first line of a file makes the code a whole lot easier. Your code attempt is not using string substitution. String substitution works like this: `set var=%foo:oldstring=newstring%`. When you need to do it with delayed expansion, then you need to first use the `setlocal` command to enable delayed expansion and then you change the percent symbols with exclamation points.

Comment: i updated it again but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: You are setting the variable `var`.  You need to `echo !var!`. Remove the equals symbol from `SETLOCAL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to do this.  You can read the file with a `FOR /F` command or if you are just editing a single line file then you can use the `SET /P` command.

Here are both of those examples in a single batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%G in (sotemp.txt) do (
    set "line=%%G"
    set "foo=!line:"media"=aa"media"!"
    echo !foo!
)

set /p "line="<sotemp.txt
echo %line:"media"=aa"media"%
pause
```

Comment: i don't know why but none of them seems to work, the first one does nothing and the second just loads the file content in the command prompt, also after fixing my initial code like you told me, the result file have only the first substring in it.  
P.S something i forgot to mention is the long string consists of a bunch of substrings seperated by a coma, with "media" being one of those substrings, that's why i used "delims=,"

Comment: I did test the code with a limited example based on your description and it works on my end. Without seeing an exact representation of your input and output it will make it nearly impossible for me to troubleshoot for you.

Comment: **input (file1):** abcd"galaxy",efghij"bar",klmno"media",pqrst"hero"   **output (file2):** abcd"galaxy",efghij"bar",klmnoaa"media",pqrst"hero"

Comment: scratch that, the first option worked perfectly, it was a dumb mistake from my part! thanks a lot man!